# Can I log current using a voltage input and V=IR

Tags: voltage, current, datalogger

I have a sensor which produces a current proportional to the variable it is sensing. My data logger only accepts input as a varying voltage, which it then encodes in 8 bits (scaled linearly to volts). Can I somehow use this and a knowledge of the equation V=IR to allow me to  measure the current (and therefore the variable that the current is proportional to) with my datalogger? Or would I need to find a logger that can log current directly?

Comment: Can you link to your sensor datasheet, that will help users answer what is probably a simple solution but might be quite complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Pass the current through a resistor to ground, then measure the voltage across that resistor with your data logger.

Answer (score 2):

**If** the sensor is "happy" to provide a voltage output of say 1 to 5 volts then converting the current to voltage with a resistor and measuring it directly with an ADC that measures voltage is a good solution.

eg if maximum sensor output = 20 mA
 and maximum ADC voltage input is 5 volts
 you can convert max of one to the max of the other
 with a resistor such that
 R = V/I = Vimmax / Ioutmax
 In this case R = 5V/20 mA = 250 ohms
 This would be the MAXIMUM value of R that can be used. You can use any lower value for a correspondingly lower maximum voltage.
eg if you use a 100 ohm resistor.
 V at max reading = Imax x R = 20 mA x 100 ohms = 2 Volts.
 If your ADC has a max input voltage of say 5V then a 2V reading is only 40% of full scale and you are wasting possible resolution.

**From above
 - Rmax = Vmax_ADC_input / I_max_sensor_output.**

---

**Low allowable max load voltage**

In some cases the sensor has a limited amount of voltage rise that it can drive a load to and this may be far less than your ADC input max voltage. Ij such a case you would lose too much resolution by using it directly.

eg if allowable max voltage = 100 mV and Imax = 20 mA then R = V/I = 0.1/20mA = 5 ohms.

This satisfies tye sensor max allowable load voltage BUT if your ADC has a full scale range of say 5V then 0.1V is only 0.1/5 = 2% of the total range -> much resolution lost.

In such cases the normal approaoch is to amplify the voltage across the sense resistor. In this case a gain of 50 would produce 5V out at Imax = 20 mA with a 5 ohm sense resistor.

To provide precision gain in such cases it is common to use an "instrumentation" amplifier" which is just 1 or 2 or 3 opamps (cctc vary) with characteristics suited to this sort of application. More on that anon maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the sensor shares ground with your data logger then as Majenko says you can probably just connect the current source to a resistor, the other end to ground and measure the voltage across the resistor.
For instance let's say you ADC range is 5V (so 5V = 11111111) and you want to measure current from 0 to 100mA. 
5V/0.1A = 50 ohms. Each ADC step would represent 100mA/256 = 0.39mA

Often a lower sense resistor is required, so some amplification may be a good idea (e.g. in the above example use 10 x gain and a 5 ohm resistor)

If you give a few more details (sensor model, what you are sensing, etc) then we can be sure of what is best.